# How do I check when my RecycleView notifyDataSetChanged() has finished?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecycleView . I updated its adapter, and call 
`notifydatasetchanged()`

. I want to wait until the list finishes drawing

Comment: then call getLastVisiblePosition()  in new Handler()

Comment: please refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173588/how-do-i-check-when-my-listview-has-finished-redrawing), it should resolve your problem

Comment: the issue is i want to insert items in between the recycleview items , but before i insert i do some computation with  the adapter size and all, sometimes the adapter is not set yet completed before the sequence of insert is performed. so it just causes a deep lag in the code and all just turn to be a mess .

Comment: @DivyeshPatel i havnt used a handler anywer before with a list insert function , will it cause any harm to smoothness of the app? have you tries it any were?? u sure of this usage ?

Comment: Try doing your computations inside `recyclerView.post(runnable)`

Comment: I think you might be trying to solve the wrong problem here. What is it that you are trying to achieve? You can call `getItemCount()` to get the adapter size. `getItemCount` is implemented by you. There is no need to wait for the list to finish drawing before you call `getItemCount` usually.

Answer (score 6):

just add this:

```
recycler.post(() -> {
    do something...
});
```

done.

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
 recyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        //At this point the layout is complete and the 
                        //dimensions of recyclerView and any child views are known.
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This is gonna called multiple times.

Comment: add this `list.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);`