# spinner selected item change event triggers in initialization

Tags: android, spinner

In my android app I have a spinner that I initialize with some categories

```
public void loadData()
{
    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                String link="http://"+Static.host+"/allcategories/?format=json";
                String json="";
                URL url = new URL(link);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    json += line;
                }
                in.close();
                JSONArray elements=new JSONArray(json);
                for (int i = 0; i < elements.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject category=elements.getJSONObject(i);
                    spinnerArray.add(category.getString("title"));
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    try
    {
        t.join();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I created a function that will search articles based on the selected category

```
public void getArticlesByCategory(String category)
{
    // I search articles and I display them in a listview
}
```

Then I created an event listener for the spinner

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
    {
        getArticlesByCategory(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView)
    {
    }
});
```

Finally I call loadData in onCreate

```
loadData();
```

The problem is that the event is triggered in the initialization of the spinner, which causes getArticlesByCategory to be called every time a new element is added.

I would like to know how I can trigger the event only when I manually select from the spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expected the solution above to work but if it doesn't a simple boolean flag would allow you to detect when the items are loaded.

1.Create a `boolean isDataLoaded = false;`

2.Add a condition in your `onItemSelected` listener

```
if (isDataLoaded) { //sort categories };
```

3.When the data loaded just set the boolean to `true`;

Answer (score 1):

This appened to me also a couple of times, try calling your `loadData()` method before adding the `setOnItemSelectedListener(...)`

This will add the items before the event listener is set and will not trigger it

Hope this helps

## Edit from comment

If you populate a list in an `async thread`, it goes on the `background` thread and 99% it will finish after the `listener` is instantiated.

So, if you want to populate after the async thread, add the listener initialization in your `thread` after the item's loading using `context.RunOnUiThread(...)` (or better, [use AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example))

IE: instantiate the listener where you call `spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in `loadData()`

## Edit number 2

Ok, you have two possibilities at this point, I don't know why it doesn't work the above for you.

1. Add a check for l`astSelectedItem != newSelectedItem` and if true, run your code inside the listener, if it is false, the selected item is not changing and you can skip the event.
2. Watch [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29173680/4700782) and add the listener as explained

Comment: I have already done it but the same problem happens. I'm using a thread to populate categories and when I removed the code from the thread the event didn't trigger but the categories aren't added

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I added a comment on "how to use it async" in my answer. You can still load it asynchronously if you want, there are no need to block ui thread :)

Comment: I instanciated the listener after spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but it still triggering

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi where do you call the `spinner.setItemSource(spinnerArray)`? (or how it is, i got no compiler atm)

Comment: In onCreated I call this : spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);adapter = new ArticleAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.article, articles);spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I don't know why it doesn't work for you honestly, there are two workaround that comes in my mind actuallym I added those to the answer