# How to set text in listview after notifyDataSetChanged() has been called

Tags: java, android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

**The Scenario:** I have a *ListView* that, when a child is clicked on by the user, sets the value of the *TextView* inside of the *ListView* through the main activity.

I have a *FloatingActionButton* that adds and subtracts an object to count the amount of items in the *ListView*.

To add or subtract the amount of children the *ListView* shows, i call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I'm trying to set the text entered back into the *TextView* after `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called

---

**The Problem:** `notifyDataSetChanged()` resets the TextView back to blank after 
it is finished running.

**What I've Tried:** I'ved tried saving all the values within the *ListView* items into a separate `String[] savedItems` and set the text within the *TextView*. I've run the code step by step within the debugger and see that the code is saving the text and actually setting the text but for some reason, `notifyDataSetChanged()` has not completed its job.

How do I set the text after `notifyDataSetChanged()` has finished?

---

**Code in Question:**

```
public void addNewThought(int numberOfThoughts) {
    String[] savedDistortionsList = saveDistortions(); // This saves each childs text

    selectedItems[numberOfThoughts] = new ArrayList<String>();
    IntegerNumberOfThoughts.add(Integer.toString((numberOfThoughts++)) ); // Just the variable that counts the number of children needed in ListView

    distortionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Refresh ListView
    setBackDistortionsList(savedDistortionsList); // Put back text into ListView
}
```

`saveDistortions()` works so I don't think it's necessary to show but here is the code to `setBackDistortionsList()` which I've tested and it actually is setting the TextView in the ListView but it just is not showing for some reason.

**setBackDistortionsList**

```
private void setBackDistortionsList(String[] savedDistortionsList) {
    View tempView;
    TextView tempTextView;
    for (int i = 0; i < savedDistortionsList.length; i++) {
        tempView = LDistortions.getChildAt(i);
        tempTextView = (TextView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.textEntry);
        tempTextView.setText(savedDistortionsList[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found here:
[How do I check when my ListView has finished redrawing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173588/how-do-i-check-when-my-listview-has-finished-redrawing)

Copy & Paste from the user @Petro

Hopefully this can help:

- Setup a addOnLayoutChangeListener on the listview
- Call .notifyDataSetChanged();
- This will fire off the OnLayoutChangeListener once completed
- Remove the listener
- Perform code on update (`getLastVisiblePosition()`)

  ```
  mListView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {

    @Override
  public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
      mListView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
      Log.e(TAG, "updated");
    }
  });

  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  ```