# Error performing 'android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction' on view with id

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-espresso

Is there any possibility:

**- to disable all animation for recycler view or run them on UI thread for testing with espresso?**

***Or***

**- to add idlingresources to android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter?**

The problem is the following: The exception is thrown for Espresso test

> android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction@3d4956f' on view 'with id: XXX:id/items_rcv'.

When trying to execute the following code:

```
//... code that executes recyclerView.adapter.submitList(items)
onView(withId(R.id.items_rcv))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<ViewHolder>(
                0, click()
            ));
```

The problem is that items are not visible when a click action is executed. They are shown with some delay because adapter for RecyclerView is extended from **android.support.v7.recyclerview.extensions.ListAdapter**:

```
class ItemsAdapter : ListAdapter<Item, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
...
}
```

so it uses the AsyncListDiffer which shows items in recycler view with some animation.

Thank You in advance

UPDATE:

The following does **not** help:
1) set BackgroundThreadExecutor as MainThreadExecutor for AsyncListDiffer

```
ItemsAdapter(AsyncDifferConfig.Builder<Item>(ItemsDiffCallback)
                    .setBackgroundThreadExecutor(MainThreadExecutor())
                    .build())
```

2) disable itemAnimator for RecyclerView

```
mActivityTestRule.activity.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.items_rcv).itemAnimator = null
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a [CountingIdlingResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/idling/CountingIdlingResource) and increment before you populate your List and decrement after its all done.

Just remember to register the IdlingResource on your @Before and @After, like so

```
IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(rule.getIdlingResource()); //before
IdlingRegistry.getInstance().unregister(rule.getIdlingResource()); //after
```

Comment: Do you know any callback in ListAdapter for decrementing after its all done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173588/how-do-i-check-when-my-listview-has-finished-redrawing/29173680#29173680